# StandardServletContainer for Runtime Target in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclipse-wtp

For a generic project its possible to add a `JRE_CONTAINER` to classpath, is something like this possible for the Web Container Server Runtime?

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe so. I'm running Eclipse Galileo and I can change the JRE by:

- Right clicking the project
- Selecting `Properties`
- Selecting `Java Build Path`
- Selecting the `Libraries` tab

Alternatively, you could also manually change the `.classpath` file. Finally, you could use a build manager such as Maven to manage the versions/libraries used.

Comment: I want a Standard Servlet Container, just as the defined `Execution Enviroments` (can be found under `Java > Installed JREs > Execution Enviroment`), this doesn't fit my question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you can add the jars of your configured server via `Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Server Runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

For projects dealing with WTP (Web Tool Platform) you do [see those kind of entries](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/stp-commits/msg02412.html):

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/j2sdk1.6.0_12"/>
```

or [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/swtbot-dev/msg00056.html):

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
```

They can come with a definition:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
```

Found also in [relation with JRE warnings](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg77497.html).

Comment: I need something like the StandardVMType `J2SE-1.5` for the Standard Servlet Container which supports the default `servlet-api` etc.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i can understand your question, you want to change the jvm version.
This you can do by going to preferences> java. there you can change the jvm version.This will take affect on the whole workspace. As far as i know , you cant have different java versions for different projects.

Comment: Yes we can ! :) On the "preferences > java" you can select the "enable projects specific settings" and select a different jvm for a specific project...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but you can declare a Library to you're runtime "Build Path > Libraries > Add Library" or you can declare your own variable "Build Path > Libraries > Add Variable" which can contain the jars you want...